# Open jquery mobile dialog from javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile

Is it possible to open a dialog in Jquery Mobile from javascript?

I tried doing something like this but it didnt work:

```
    <a id='lnkDialog' href="goals.html" data-rel="dialog" data-transition="pop" style='display:none;'></a>
```

and then in js

```
        document.getElementById('lnkDialog').click();
```

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

We'll need a lot more information, but unless #lnkDialog already has a function binded to a click event, that's not going to work.  I'm assuming the data-rel contains the ID of the modal that will pop up.

It'd be more like

```
$('#lnkDialog').on({
    click:
        function() {
            var selector = '#' + $(this).attr('data-rel');
            $(selector).show();
        }
});
```

but again, a LOT more information needed.

Answer (score 1):

Here's what i do.

In my markup i have a dialog defined inside body, towards the end of it as follows:

```
<div data-role="dialog" id="messagebox">
    <div data-role="header">
        <h1>Message</h1>
    </div><!-- /header -->

    <div data-role="content">
        <span id="phMessage"></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Then in javascript I have:

```
function showMessage(message) {
    $("#phMessage").html(message);
    $.mobile.changePage('#messagebox', 'pop', false, true);
}
```

The only thing you really need is `$.mobile.changePage('#messagebox', 'pop', false, true);`

Comment: Weird, didn't work for me. Nothing happens when I call that function

Comment: Could you create a jsfiddle and show us? Make sure dialog div has data-role equal to "dialog"